# How create a query with a join in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, join

I need to do the following query using the CakePHP find method:

```
SELECT * FROM fydee.clients_groups join clients on clients_groups.client_id = clients.id where clients.deleted = 0 and group_id = 7;
```

The Client_groups.client_id field is the same as the clients.idfield, so that's what the join is on. How can i create this in cakephp?

i have tried:

```
$clients = $this->Groups->find('all', array(
            'joins' => array(
                array(
                    'table' => 'Clients',
                    'alias' => 'ClientsJoin',
                    'type' => 'INNER',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'ClientsJoin.id = client.id'
                    )
                )
            ),
            'conditions' => array(
                'Group.id' => $_POST['group_id'],
                'Client.deleted' => 0
            )
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to do something like this:-

```
$this->Group->find('all', [
    'joins' => [
        [
            'table' => 'clients',
            'alias' => 'Client',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => [
                'Client.id = Group.client_id'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'conditions' => [
        'Group.id' => $_POST['group_id'],
        'Client.deleted' => 0
    ]
]);
```

When you declare an `alias` in the `joins` it is the alias of the table you are joining. So following CakePHP naming conventions wants to be something like `Client`. Your join condition then needs to be `'Client.id = Group.client_id'`.

You could probably achieve the same result more simply using a `contain` (assuming your model associations are correctly set up) like:-

```
$this->Group->find('all', [
    'contain' => ['Client'],
    'conditions' => [
        'Group.id' => $_POST['group_id'],
        'Client.deleted' => 0
    ]
]);
```

On a side note you should really be using `$this->request->data` rather than `$_POST` in Cake.

Comment: The query sends 0 records back.


'query' => 'SELECT `Group`.`id`, `Group`.`name`, `Group`.`slidesperad`, `Group`.`deleted`, `Group`.`modified`, `Group`.`created` FROM `fydee`.`groups` AS `Group` INNER JOIN `fydee`.`clients` AS `Client` ON (`Client`.`id` = `Group`.`id`)  WHERE `Group`.`id` = 7 AND `Client`.`deleted` = 0 AND `Group`.`deleted` = 0',
   'params' => array(),
   'affected' => (int) 0,
   'numRows' => (int) 0,
   'took' => (float) 0

Comment: Your issue looks to be with your join condition. Do you mean `Client.id = Group.client_id` instead of `Client.id = Group.id`?

Comment: i have fix the query, the join was the problem.

Comment: @RichardHoek Great! If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer to help others with a similar problem to you. :-)